# Create a new table that combines (UNION) several tables with the same column structure

Tags: sql-server

I get this error:  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'.

When trying to do this:

```
Create Tables new_table
Select * , 'XXX1' as XField
From old_table1
UNION ALL
Select * , 'XXX2' as XField
From old_table2
UNION ALL
Select * , 'XXX3' as XField
From old_table3
```

I tried other suggestions from stackoverflow related to creating new tables with union but not of the solutions worked

```
Create Tables new_table
Select * , 'XXX1' as XField
From old_table1
UNION ALL
Select * , 'XXX2' as XField
From old_table2
UNION ALL
Select * , 'XXX3' as XField
From old_table3
```

I expect (after long processing time b/c I used UNION ALL) that my result will be a new table with all of fields and my user defined field.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views?view=sql-server-2017):

```
create view new_table as
select ...
union all
select ...
etc
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [`SELECT ... INTO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select * into new_table
from (
  Select * , 'XXX1' as XField
  From old_table1
  UNION ALL
  Select * , 'XXX2' as XField
  From old_table2
  UNION ALL
  Select * , 'XXX3' as XField
  From old_table3
) t;
```

Comment: There is no need to repeat the alias, you need just the first one.